# C# Windows 7 problem

Tags: c#, windows-7, operating-system

I develop a windows application on c#.

I have tried it on different PCs with XP operating system, but I had a problem when I start to run on PC with windows 7.

The program is closed automatically.

I use SQLite for database and interaction with php files in the program.

Comment: Have you already looked in event-log? A bit more information would be great? What is your program doing.

Comment: You need to describe in more detail what happens. Do you get an error message when it closes or does it just disappear? Check the event log, are there any messages there? What version of the .net framework is installed? What version is your app built against? Have you tried it on more that one windows 7 PC?

Comment: You're going to need to provide a little more info! Could you post the contents of Main(), perhaps?

Comment: program gets datas from SQLite.and wors on this datas and stores back.i use php files for password control or something like this.

it closed with any error message.just dissapper.I built aplication with VS 2005  edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just guessing, could it be that the Windows 7 operating system is 64-bit? If yes, and you're using the 32-bit version of SQlite, you might have forgotten to make your C# a 32-bit only project.

To do so, open the project properties, and on the Build page, select x86 (which means 32-bit).

Comment: Yes That is the answer Stefan.Great Thanks.I dont know how to mark it as answer bu it is the reel solition

Comment: try clicking on the tick under the votes of the correct answer